# Constrained Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string, constrained-dynamics

> There are two bodies viz. A and B which are placed on a horizontal
>   surface. The free end P is being pulled by a constant force of **1 N**.
>   Find the acceleration of free end P?

[image: Figure]

***My approach***

Sign convention -––> Left is considered to be negative and right is considered to be positive.

String is considered to be massless.

So at point P,

$F - T = ma = 0$

=> $F = T = 1 N$

According to my perception,

*The tension is same throughout the string.*

So the block A is in contact at two points.

So overall Force that is pulling the block A is 3 N. (Due to Tension force acting on the pulleys)

Similarly, The force acting on Block B is -4 N.

So both the blocks must have an acceleration of 1m/s^2. (A towards right and B towards left)

So now using,

$ a_{pulley} = \frac{a_{string1} + a_{string2}}{2}$

[image: figure 2]

Using this,

**$a_{string}  at point p = 7\frac{m}{s^2}$**

Is this the most efficient way to solve this problem?